# How to perform mathematical operations on some fields in Python?

Tags: python-2.7

Some query in a database allows me to count the number of documents it contains, grouped by the different values of a key. Here is a sample of the result:

```
{('value1',): 3, ('value2',): 11, (u'value3',): 5, (u'value4',): 35, ('value5',): 3, etc.}
```

I would like to compute the average and the median of 3, 11, 5, 35, 3, etc. with Python. How can I extract these values and compute them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how you're getting the results, but something like this would work.

```
arr = {('value1',): 3, ('value2',): 11, (u'value3',): 5, (u'value4',): 35, ('value5',): 3}
vals = arr.values() # Get list of values, [3, 11, 5, 34, 3]
average = reduce(lambda x,y: (x + y) / 2.0, vals)
# Perform whatever operations you want
```

If you're using numpy, you can get the median with `numpy.median(numpy.array(vals))`

Comment: Wow, thx! 3d line didn't work for me, but I think 1st and 2d will do. Got the result form RethinkDB python client 
`a = r.db('somebase').table('sometable').group('somekey').count().run()` then `b = a.values()` and then `numpy.mean(b)`.